# Automatically enclose \glt line from gb4e in \enquote{}

Tags: macros, punctuation, linguistics, csquotes, gb4e

How can I automatically enclose the \glt (\trans) line in gb4e's interlinear glosses in context-aware quotation marks with \enquote{} from csquotes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex 
    \gll Etwas fremdsprachiger Text \\
         some {foreign language-y} text \\
    \glt \enquote{Free translation.}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to just type

```
\glt Free translation.
```

and have that rendered as

```
“Free translation.”
```

in the resulting PDF.

Comment: Will `\glt` *always* be the last entry within the `exe` environment? If you have such consistency, one could perhaps insert the `\enquote` upon usage of `\glt`. If not, provide us with a more comprehensive set of usages of `\glt`.

Comment: While `\gll` is pretty strict on its input (two lines delimited by ``\\``), `\glt` accepts anything. Would you accept having to type ``\glt Free translation \\``?

Comment: egreg: Yes, that would be OK, too.

Werner: See the [documentation for gb4e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gb4e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\glt` to capture content up to some ending delimiter. Below I've used `\end` from `\end{exe}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
  \ex 
  \gll Etwas fremdsprachiger Text \\
       some {foreign language-y} text \\
  \glt \enquote{Free translation.}
\end{exe}

% Now redefine \glt to capture everything up to \end{exe}
\let\oldglt\glt
\long\def\glt #1 \end{\oldglt \enquote{#1}\end}

\begin{exe}
  \ex 
  \gll Etwas fremdsprachiger Text \\
       some {foreign language-y} text \\
  \glt Free translation.
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Depending on your use-case, other delimiters can also be used to capture the scope of the `\enquote` (like `\\` - suggested in comment).