# How can I tweak linguex so that the first line of a glossed example is in italics?

Tags: linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e

I have used the linguex package for an article; now it turns out that in the glossed examples the original text (the first line) should be in italics. Can someone tell me how/where I can tweak the definitions in linguex so that this happens?

Ideally also the translation (final line) should be enclosed in single quotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\exg. Das ist kein Beispiel. \\
      that is   no example \\
      That is not an example.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: `linguex` uses the `cgloss4e` macros for glossing, so you can just put `\renewcommand*{\eachwordone}{\itshape}` in your preamble, like in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185560/32888). Automagically enclosing translations in quotes might be a little trickier (or impossible) to do, depending on how you write translations in your document. Do you use the `\glt` macro? Like @Andrew said, I think we might need a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: For example, the [answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215007/32888) for `gb4e` relies on the fact that all examples end with `\end{exe}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @andrew and @adam-liter.  Using `\renewcommand\eachwordone\itshape` did the trick for the italic first line.  I learned from a helpful colleague that \eachwordtwo will get at the gloss line, potentially also helpful in future. But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do the same thing for the translation line, should one ever want to, for the reason suggested in the answer referred to by Adam.   I can live with adding quotes by hand, turned out i had already done so for half anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can redefine the formatting of the gloss lines by using:

```
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape}
```

and similarly for `\eachwordtwo` and `\eachwordthree` for the second or third gloss line formatting.

You should probably be using the `\glt` macro for your translation lines. If you do, it's easy to redefine it to add quotation marks.  Here I use the `csquotes` package, which can do many nice things with quotations more generally. Using it is useful because if you need to change the quotation style of the translation line you can quite easily. To see the power of this, I've used two different languages in the same document, and the quote style changes appropriately. (This is for example purposes only; a more likely scenario would be using the same examples in documents of different languages.)

Note that you need to wrap the argument of `\glt` in braces, but I've added code to remove leading and trailing spaces within the argument.

The `csquotes` packages allows proper nesting of quotation marks and so defines both an "outer" and "inner" quotation mark. By default, in English the outer marks are double and the inner marks are single.  To force use of the inner mark only (and thereby get single quotes in English) you can use `\enquote*` instead of `\enquote` in the redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\glt}[1]{\vskip.17\baselineskip\enquote{\trim@spaces#1}} 
% use \enquote* for inner quote mark
% \vskip.17\baselineskip is in the original cgloss code; it can be removed
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\exg. Das ist kein Beispiel. \\
      that is   no example \\
\glt{   That is not an example.}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\exg. Das ist kein Beispiel. \\
      that is   no example \\
\glt{That is not an example.}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: +1 Though I think the OP said that they wanted/needed single quotes.

Comment: @AdamLiter I've added some more explanation.

Comment: Great information. For the record I found that `\eachwordthree` doesn't get at the translation line, so it's very useful to know how to use the `\glt` macro.

Comment: @Caroline Right, `\eachwordthree` is for *three line* glosses introduced with the `\glll` command. It is not the translation line. The `linguex` package hides this functionality by wrapping the glossing macros in its own macros and so effectively only allows two gloss lines. (I use `gb4e` which uses the glossing macros as written.)